# Android Support Library appcompat_v7 v21.0.1 gives error

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Every thing worked fine before updating sdk and support libraries. After updating i just added the support library(mean imported the support library with resources). once i add it i get the following error

**Error:**

```
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.       
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
    [2014-11-12 13:28:16 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
```

**After changing my Build Target to 21 from 17 i get these errors**

```
[2014-11-12 13:33:15 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-12 13:33:15 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2014-11-12 13:33:15 - android-support-v7-appcompat] E:\Android Projects\android-support-v7-appcompat\res\values-large-v14\themes_base.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.Base.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge.Base'.
[2014-11-12 13:33:15 - android-support-v7-appcompat]
```

I tried a lot of things like importing the project again changing the project.properties file etc., I am not able to solve the issue

please help me out thanks in advance.

Comment: once restart your eclipse !!!

Comment: remove this theme from values-v14 folder or include material design lib

Comment: where do you have v21.0.1 from? The last version I have seen in the wild is 21.0.0

Comment: @Duggu tried that too..

Comment: @SuhailMehta material design lib means..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify the project.properties file, which has:

```
target=android-19
```

to

```
target=android-21
```

after changes above close project then open and clean

Comment: Now I remember I did this last time. Good reminder. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to comment but I'm too low on reputation.
I run into the same issue once when changing my pc so I used to export the library from my old pc and imported that one into the new one afaik. You can give it a try but I can not guarantee that it works for you as well.
You can use my exported library if you want to. Eventhough it doesn't make much sense, for some reason it worked for me after that.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ly9mhmlvthk15f9/Libraries.zip?dl=0

Comment: after adding your library i get this error  Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: I hope you can follow that guys answer there. That's what I also used.